# When trying to produce DSM (digital surface model) in R using the lidR package I get Error: no first returns found. Operations aborted

Tags: r, gis

Basically what the title says. I have a .las 3d point cloud file, and I'm trying to turn it into a canopy height model in R.

I use this code to make the DSM

```
dsm_2L<- grid_canopy(las = pc, res = 0.1, algorithm = dsmtin())

Error: No first returns found. Operation aborted.
```

How can I trouble shoot this to figure out why it's not returning any value?

Comment: what does `ctg <- readLAScatalog("path/to/las/files/"pc)` tell you about `pc`?

Comment: class       : LAScatalog (v1.2 format 3)
extent      : 510998.4, 511424.4, 5206412, 5206955 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 10N 
area        : 231416.4 m²
points      : 2.27 million points
density     : 9.8 points/m²
num. files  : 1

Comment: lidR version 4.0.1

To bring the las file "pc" into R I simply typed the command 
pc = readLAS("d:/GIS_in_R/uav.las")

after this I attempted to classify the ground with 
pc = lasground(las = pc, algorithm = csf())

however it said lasground is defunct and to use classify_ground instead.

when using las_check it has a few issues. 
 ⚠ Invalid data: 2266197 points with a return number equal to 0 found.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1q0madyqnwg5dug/pc.las?dl=0

Comment: las_check shows a few issues. 
⚠ Invalid data: 2266197 points with a return number equal to 0 found.
⚠ Invalid data: 2266197 points with a number of returns equal to 0 found.
⚠ 7 points are duplicated and share XYZ coordinates with other points
Checking degenerated ground points...
⚠ There were 3 degenerated ground points. Some X Y Z coordinates were repeated
⚠ There were 82 degenerated ground points. Some X Y coordinates were repeated but with different Z coordinates
- Checking gpstime incoherances
✗ 1 pulses (points with the same gpstime) have points with identical ReturnNumber

Comment: Interestingly read las then plot and it plots something useful....so, the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This data is wonderfully horrible, but things can be done with it, and I have a lot more to review in [lidR - the book](https://r-lidar.github.io/lidRbook/index.html), but fishing around with `RGB` plots,

```
pc_las <- readLAS('~/Downloads/pc.las')
Warning messages:
1: Invalid data: 2266197 points with a return number equal to 0 found. 
2: Invalid data: 2266197 points with a number of returns equal to 0 found.


> canopy_p2r <- rasterize_canopy(pc_las, res = 0.1, algorithm = p2r(0.2)) 
# p2r(0.2) enlarges point to disc, improves result image
```

[image]

There was a clue in looking at the `plot(pc_las, color= RGB)`. You can see a 'water tower', and yet, the extent says, no way you'd see that. Note the little red area toward lower left of an aster dem of the study area.

Here, click/pick points out around `canopy_p2r` to make a polygon to crop with.

```
plot(canopy_p2r)
pts <- click(canopy_p2r, n=30, xy = TRUE)
pts_mtx <- as.matrix(pts[, 1:2])
can_poly <- vect(pts_mtx, type= 'polygons', crs = 'EPSG:32610')
can_poly_4326 <- project(can_poly, 'EPSG:4326')
ext(can_poly_4326)
SpatExtent : -122.855230404662, -122.849695629639, 47.0111456525597, 47.0158802976408 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

Use the SpatExtent at `NASA-EarthData` to get an Aster dem. Note: Type, don't copy/paste the xmin& etc in the 'select by rectangle', as they (reasonably?) expect SQL injection and it will repeatedly fail...sigh.

[image]

```
ast_dem <- rast('~/Downloads/ASTGTMV003_N47W123_dem.tif')
# crop ast_dem by can_poly_4326
ast_crop_4326 <- crop(ast_dem, can_poly_4326)
# project this to EPSG:32610
ast_crop_32610 <- project(ast_crop_4326, 'EPSG:32610')
ext(ast_crop_32610)
SpatExtent : 511009.866154932, 511420.434414284, 5206436.81511609, 5206950.02544028 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

looking at ?lidR::clip_rectangle, we see it wants a different order than returned by out SpatExtent, but we want to get rid of as many extraneous NA as we can.

```
clip_pc <- clip_rectangle(pc_las, xleft=unname(ext(ast_crop_32610)[c(1,3,2,4)][1]), ybottom = unname(ext(ast_crop_32610)[c(1,3,2,4)][2]), xright=unname(ext(ast_crop_32610)[c(1,3,2,4)][3]), ytop=unname(ext(ast_crop_32610)[c(1,3,2,4)][4]))
library(rgl)
x = plot(clip_pc, bg = 'white', size = 3)
add_dtm3d(x, ast_crop_32610)
```

[image]

And now, (assuming all this wasn't unnecessary) we can move along to the classification problem...

```
# install.packages('RCSF', dependencies = TRUE) uncomment if needed
mycsf <- csf(TRUE, 1, 1, time_step = 1)
clip_pc <- classify_ground(clip_pc, mycsf)
plot(clip_pc, color = 'Classification')
```

and we seem to be getting somewhere... where blue is ground and grey/black other than ground. Now, how to get the tower to '2'.

[image]

```
#returning to the click approach for 'water tower'
plot(canopy_p2r)
pts_tower <- click(canopy_p2r, n = 6, xy = TRUE)  
pts_tower[7, ] <- pts_tower[1, ]
tower_roi <- st_polygon(list(as.matrix(pts_tower[, 1:2])))
# classify tower
clip_pc <- classify_poi(clip_pc, LASBUILDING, roi = st_sfc(tower_roi, crs = 32610), inverse = FALSE)
poi <- ~Classification !=LASGROUND
clip_pc <- classify_poi(clip_pc, LASHIGHVEGETATION, poi = poi, roi = st_sfc(tower_roi, crs = 32610), inverse = TRUE)
```

And things at this point are 'bulk' classified, but there's still the 'returns' question. But I suppose the first thing we are set up to do is `normalization` while we further investigate if `returns` can be evaluated after the fact. And save till here

```
writeLAS(clip_pc, file = 'semi_processed.las', index = TRUE)
```

Anticipating some headway on `first_returns`. Well, more likely not.
Any returns require a timestamp.

```
summary(clip_pc@data)
       X                Y                 Z             gpstime    Intensity
 Min.   :511010   Min.   :5206432   Min.   : 62.66   Min.   :0   Min.   :0  
 1st Qu.:511113   1st Qu.:5206581   1st Qu.: 84.13   1st Qu.:0   1st Qu.:0  
 Median :511206   Median :5206675   Median : 94.45   Median :0   Median :0  
 Mean   :511204   Mean   :5206684   Mean   : 92.93   Mean   :0   Mean   :0  
 3rd Qu.:511289   3rd Qu.:5206784   3rd Qu.:100.75   3rd Qu.:0   3rd Qu.:0  
 Max.   :511424   Max.   :5206950   Max.   :138.43   Max.   :0   Max.   :0  
  ReturnNumber NumberOfReturns ScanDirectionFlag EdgeOfFlightline
 Min.   :0     Min.   :0       Min.   :0         Min.   :0       
 1st Qu.:0     1st Qu.:0       1st Qu.:0         1st Qu.:0       
 Median :0     Median :0       Median :0         Median :0       
 Mean   :0     Mean   :0       Mean   :0         Mean   :0       
 3rd Qu.:0     3rd Qu.:0       3rd Qu.:0         3rd Qu.:0       
 Max.   :0     Max.   :0       Max.   :0         Max.   :0       
 Classification Synthetic_flag  Keypoint_flag   Withheld_flag   ScanAngleRank
 Min.   :2.00   Mode :logical   Mode :logical   Mode :logical   Min.   :0    
 1st Qu.:5.00   FALSE:2232003   FALSE:2232003   FALSE:2232003   1st Qu.:0    
 Median :5.00                                                   Median :0    
 Mean   :4.34                                                   Mean   :0    
 3rd Qu.:5.00                                                   3rd Qu.:0    
 Max.   :6.00                                                   Max.   :0    
    UserData PointSourceID       R               G               B        
 Min.   :0   Min.   :0     Min.   :    0   Min.   : 3328   Min.   :  256  
 1st Qu.:0   1st Qu.:0     1st Qu.:16384   1st Qu.:24832   1st Qu.:17408  
 Median :0   Median :0     Median :28672   Median :36096   Median :24832  
 Mean   :0   Mean   :0     Mean   :28732   Mean   :35534   Mean   :25653  
 3rd Qu.:0   3rd Qu.:0     3rd Qu.:40192   3rd Qu.:46336   3rd Qu.:32512  
 Max.   :0   Max.   :0     Max.   :65280   Max.   :65280   Max.   :65280  

length(which(clip_pc@data$Classification == 0))
[1] 0
```

Well, everything is Classified, if perhaps improperly. Without timestamps, as are above missing in summary, hard to 'populate'/ create returns and the like. But not a complete fiasco. And `normalization` can still be done given these present objects: an exercise for the user. Best to ask, whomever sent this data, where'd you get it?